# How do you run a Lucene fuzzy query only on the non-nummeric part of a string?

Tags: apache, lucene

I want to run a FuzzyQuery on a string which may or may not contain numeric characters in it. I want the query to not match on any edits to the numeric characters. For instance If I fed in "123abc" then I want all my matches to still contain "123" in the beginning. So I would expect matches like "123abg" "123ab" "123cbc" but I would not want something like "124abc".

Comment: Is the part you want *not* to be fuzzy is always at the beginning?  If so, you can set a PrefixLength (which is good for performance, as well).

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the number will not necessarily appear at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Suspected as much.  In that case, the best idea I have is to analyze the parts into separate tokens (see [WordDelimiterFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html)), then you could construct a `SpanQuery` that would work.

Comment: Thanks! This looks pretty good, I'll check it out.